# Rails 3 Timer to run a method (Delayed Job)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timer, server-side

I want to set a timer on server side to run a method at a specific time. Has anybody done this using just rails and no AJAX? Thanks a lot. I'd appreciate any input :)

update:
I've read about Delayed Job written by the amazing guys at Shopify. I think this might just do the trick

Comment: Don't think this needs any additional information. Sounds like he's basically looking for cron-type functionality in Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little too vague to answer concisely. You may be looking for one of the following things:

- A client-side redirect on a timer with `http-equiv` headers.
- A `cron` task that executes `rails runner` on a regular schedule.
- A timeout on an operation being performed, such as using `Timeout`.

Comment: Hi tadman, from what i've researched so far, it seems like Delayed Job (https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#readme) might do the trick. Thanks for your input.